# Add and remove divs with Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a site with video backgrounds that are preloaded so all my content needs to be on the same page. I have a div with my first section in it as "slide1" for example. I need to remove this div and replace it with "slide2" on a button click. I've tried using javascript to load "slide2"s html in on the click but the code I've tried just writes the div to a white page with no styling. I need it to be loaded inside my content div with the appropriate stylings in place.

my html code:

```
<script src="assets/js/introduction.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="content">


    <div id="slide1">
    <p>Here is the first trigger. It should look something like this</p>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="part2()" value="Click Me!" /></p>
    </div>



</div>
```

the javascript file with the content:

```
function part2() {
    document.write('\
      <div id="slide2">\
        <p>Here is the second trigger. It should be to the left</p>\
        <p>next line goes here</p>\
      </div>'
    );
}
```

I've been stuck on this for days and it's driving me insane. Any help would be great

Comment: Do you know what `document.write` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create all the slides in the html and hide all of them except slide 1?
Then when they click the button hide slide 1 and show slide 2. Something like this

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
 <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
 <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
 <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="next-button">Next</a>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  var currentSlide = 0;
  $(".slide").hide();
  $(".slide:eq(0)").show();
  $("#next-button").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".slide:eq(" + currentSlide + ")").hide();
    if(currentSlide == $(".slide").length - 1){
      currentSlide = 0;   
    }else{
        currentSlide++;
    }
    $(".slide:eq("+ currentSlide +")").show();
  });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cNTgQ/1/

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want! I just don't know how to achieve that. I thought the way I was attempting was sort of that. As you can tell I'm new to this.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. If you are going to provide an answer give the OP some code that s/he can work with.

Comment: I am making a damn fiddle.Uno Momento.

Comment: @user3399142 something like that? See Fiddle. Updated for looping back around at last slide.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Had a lot on my plate. That has worked perfectly. You even took it a step further than I needed with the slide counting. You have no idea how greatful I am

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with JQuery try using `.replaceWith()`

See the [official](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
    function part2() {

    var html = '<div id="slide2"><p>Here is the second trigger. It should be to the left</p><p>next line goes here</p></div>';
//here you append the slide2;
    $('#content').append(html);
//here you remove it
    $('#slide1').remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guy said, try using replaceWith() from jQuery, here's your function:

```
 function part2() {
        var content = '<div id="slide2"><p>Here is the second trigger. It should be to the left</p><p>next line goes here</p></div>';
        $('#slide1').hide().replaceWith(content).show();
    }
```

Comment: forgot about it! Thanks!